# Bootstrap-table how to use exportOptions

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I want to change the filename that is used when using the Table Export extension. I know I can use the exportOptions to add {fileName:'custom_file_name'}. But I don't know where to put this.

I tried:

```
data-export-options="{fileName:'custom_file_name'}"
```

and I tried to add as a method:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('exportOptions', {fileName: 'custom_file_name'})
```

But then I get an error: Uncaught Error: Unknown method: exportOptions`enter code here`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following as a html table attribute:

```
data-export-options='{"fileName": "desired filename here"}'
```

Make sure you have the proper quotes and that the key is fileName with camelCase.

Answer (score 6):

Use like this:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    exportOptions: {
        fileName: 'custom_file_name'
    }
});
```

Now we do not support via data-attributes, docs: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-export.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/3365/

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesn't work. The file is still exported as tableExport. The code is executed by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default file name (tableExport) in the 'tableExport.js' file.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    tableExport: function (options) {
      var defaults = {
        consoleLog: false,
        csvEnclosure: '"',
        csvSeparator: ',',
        csvUseBOM: true,
        displayTableName: false,
        escape: false,
        excelstyles: ['border-bottom', 'border-top', 'border-left', 'border-right'],
        fileName: 'Whatever_You_Like',
        htmlContent: false,
        ignoreColumn: [],
        ignoreRow:[],
        jspdf: {orientation: 'p',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have showExport in the table tag, it needs to be in the javascript like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data,
        showExport: true,
        exportOptions: {
            fileName: 'some_file_name'
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to create the rest of your table via data attributes, you can use the refreshOptions method:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {exportOptions: {fileName: 'custom_file_name'}});
```